# CRM 2011 User Login History

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, audit

I want to track the Login History for all the user. Since, this feature is available from UR5 and onward by Enabling Auditing User access. Now, a/c to the CRM 2011, which I'm quoting here "Subsequent access by this user to MS Dynamics CRM may not be logged for the next 4 hours" and below snap is for reference:-

[image: User Access Form]

But, our client pointed out that the story is not what the above picture is telling. As they mentioned that Audit history is recording for the same user before 4 hours of time elapsed. Hardly within an interval of 6 mins as shown below:-

[image: User Access Grid]

Recording of Audit history of User Access looks like to be based on some random. Since, I'm not a big fan of Random Theory, so I'm curious to find the chemistry behind it.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it's the accessing of the same entity record without any change.  So the above screenshot relates to 2 unique User entity records.

- So for example, if you open an entity - 1 audit record
- If you refresh the entity - no audit log (unless 4 hours have passed)
- If someone else changes the entity record and then you refresh - 1 audit log
- If you open another record for the same entity - 1 audit log

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to evaluate how many users logged in to CRM:

- Analyse IIS Logs
- Audit User Access (Available since CRM 2011 RU5)

Read this post : http://dynamics.co.il/auditing-users-access-crm-2011/

Answer (score 0):

The entity record was probably changed at 11:40 AM by the system and then the user login happened. You might want to investigate this system change a bit deeper in order to find out what was actually changed.